# String method crashes program

Tags: c++, class

Alright so i have two identical string methods...

```
string CreateCust() { 
    string nameArray[] ={"Tom","Timo","Sally","Kelly","Bob","Thomas","Samantha","Maria"};
    int d = rand() % (8 - 1 + 1) + 1;   
    string e =  nameArray[d];
    return e;
   }      

string CreateFood()  {
     string nameArray[] = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};
     int d = rand() % (3 - 1 + 1) + 1;   
     string f =  nameArray[d];
     return f;
}
```

however no matter what i do it the guts of CreateFood it will always crash. i created a test chassis for it and it always fails at the `cMeal = CreateFood();`

```
        Customer Cnow;        
        cout << "test1" << endl;
        cMeal = Cnow.CreateFood();
        cout << "test1" << endl;
        cCustomer = Cnow.CreateCust();
        cout << "test1" << endl;
```

i even switched CreateCust with CreateFood and it still fails at the CreateFood Function...

NOTE: if i make createFood a int method it does work...

Also guys even if i changed CreateFood to just COUT a message and nothing more it still crashed...

Comment: When posting code, please reduce the amount of vertical whitespace to a minimum. I've fixed it for you this time, but in future consider you will get better answers if people can read your code easily.

Comment: What's with the `rand() % (8 - 1 + 1) + 1;`?  Did you decide to let the compiler do the math for you there?

Comment: haha why is everyone commenting on my rand? lol i dont know rand well my book didnt teach it well.

Comment: @Timothy Anyone who  says "lol", and can't be bothered to use the shift key automatically gets a downvote from me.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth  why dont you keep to the relevance of the comment rather than critique my grammar. after all this is a programming forum, not a place where you can harass people and act big online to compensate for your passive nature in real life.

Comment: @TimothyTech Maybe you should try to understand rand() before you use it?

Comment: @GMan I'll remember that. I just need to wait for your next answer...

Comment: @Eric thats  why im looking here, glad to know you came out of the womb with complete understanding of programming.

Comment: @Timothy: But your question has nothing to do with "can someone explain rand to me?", you've already used it. Hence his comment: don't use it until you understand it more; not "I always knew." but rather "I looked it up first." In any case, nobody here is harassing people to make up for anything. Professionalism when you're asking for help goes a long way and shows that we should be willing to put our time and effort into something because you've done the same. I've seen much worse than yours (it's not too bad), but a little "I" instead of "i" goes a long way.

Comment: @Timothy I'm genuinely interested now - why the "kewl-speak" when you can obviously construct a sentence? A bid for sympathy of some sort?

Comment: @TimothyTech The problem here is, that you use a function you don't understand and wonder why your own function is crashing. Maybe you should have asked about the unknown function first, before using it. You wouldn't try to use a car with an extra gear lever, use the lever and ask why you crashed into a wall.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth Because I was interested in getting a quick answer to resolve this issue, you have no idea how much it is killing me to not press shift now. 


@Eric Also it isnt the rand that is crashing my program. its the string type.

Comment: @TimothyTech Nope its the index, which you calculate with rand()

Comment: @Timothy: One more thing, when you ask a question you should enter "no preconceived notions" mode. If someone says it's X, even if you don't think it's X you need to consider it; if you were in a position to know, you wouldn't be asking the question. :) (In other words, asking a question is the position opposite of telling someone an answer, don't try to do both.)

Comment: @Gman im confused as to how i lost 2 points for grammar on a forum about programming. and your irrelevant opinions are no help to my issue Gman, I asked a question about Programming not a how to be a better person. And I did consider Eric's notion, but since he had only said "you shouldn't use it" the first time that didn't make much since to me, however his second reply was a bit more helpful.

Comment: Well, people *can* downvote for whatever reason. Neil puts importance in a professional presentation, and that's his way of letting you know he thinks the question is unclear. (Which is one reason for downvotes, in the tooltip.) My opinions are not relevant to your programming question, sure, but they are things I've learned make people want to help you. So take it or leave it, I'd recommend taking the advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crash is happening because you are accessing an invalid index.  This is because array indexes start from 0 and not 1, so you don't want to add a 1 to the rvalue of the modulus operator.

Here is a neat trick that you can use to make your code a little more maintainable:

```
template <class T>
T getRandElem( const T[] arr )
{
    return arr[ rand() % ( sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]) ) ];
}

string CreateCust(){ 
    static string nameArray[] = {"Tom","Timo","Sally","Kelly","Bob","Thomas","Samantha","Maria"};
    return getRandElem<string>( nameArray ); 
}

string CreateFood(){
     static string nameArray[] = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};
     return getRandElem<string>( nameArray );
}
```

Comment: dang, an answer was already accepted between when I started to post my answer and when I actually posted it.  And I thought it was a pretty good answer as well...  =(

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this code doesn't do what you think. (`sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0])` will be the size of a `const T*` over the size of a `T`.)

Comment: @GMan: I'm pretty sure that since your array size is defined at compile time, the sizeof works properly as described above.

Comment: Sorry, but it's incorrect. (By the way, it should be `const T arr[]`.) That is syntactically equivalent to `const T* arr`, and you should see that `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` is going to be `sizeof(const T*) / sizeof(const T)`, which has nothing to do with the array size. When you pass an array to this function, you're just passing a pointer to the first element, not an array. See my answer for how to pass arrays into functions (it must be by reference), and a common compile-time method of getting the array size.

Answer (score 8):

Take out the `+ 1` on both of them, you access arrays starting from 0:

```
int d = rand() % (8 - 1 + 1);  // 0-7, not 1-8
int d = rand() % (3 - 1 + 1);  // 0-2, not 1-3
```

Otherwise you're accessing a non-existent element, and this is undefined behavior. (That means it could appear to work, like in `CreateCust`, crash like in `CreateFood`, do nothing, or do anything.)

---

I'm not sure what the purpose of subtracting 1 then adding 1 is. In any case, now is the perfect time to learn: Don't Repeat Yourself. Even if you do something just twice, make a function out of it, it'll be less cryptic and more concise:

```
int random(int min, int max)
{
    return rand() % ((b - a) + 1) + a;
}
```

This is a simple function that returns a random number between `a` and `b`, inclusive. (Means it can include both `a` and `b` in the results.) Now your code reads:

```
// I'll leave CreateCust up to you

string CreateFood(void)
{
     string nameArray[] = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};

     int d = random(0, 2); // either 0, 1, or 2, randomly   
     string f =  nameArray[d];
     return f;
}
```

And you'll see even just one function makes it much easier to read; your goal is to make your code easy to read by humans. Also, this is much more concise:

```
string CreateFood(void)
{
     string nameArray[] = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};

     return nameArray[random(0, 2)];
}
```

Another bad thing to do is hardcode magic numbers into your program. For example, why 3 or 8? It can be *deduced* those are array sizes, but that doesn't stand on its own. What you might want is something like:

```
string CreateFood(void)
{
     const size_t ArraySize = 3; // 3 elements, 0-2
     string nameArray[ArraySize] = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};
                    // ^ Ensure it matches

     return nameArray[random(0, ArraySize - 1)];
}
```

Now the range for the number number makes sense up front.

---

The rest may be a bit advanced (which you won't understand until you get to templates), but shows how we might go on:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (&countof_detail(T (&)[N]))[N];

#define countof(pX) sizeof(countof_detail(pX))
```

This nifty tool will give you the number of elements in an array. The code might turn into this

```
string CreateFood(void)
{
     string nameArray[] = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};
                    // ^ no explicit size

     return nameArray[random(0, countof(nameArray) - 1)];
}
```

We got rid of any numbers altogether, you can just manipulate the array as you please. Lastly, we're repeating ourselves again: getting a random element from an array. We should make a function for that:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T& random_element(T (&pArray)[N])
{
    return pArray[random(0, N - 1)];
}
```

This returns a random element from any array. Your function would then simply be:

```
string CreateFood(void)
{
     string nameArray[] = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};

     return random_element(nameArray);
}
```

Note in this refactoring (refactoring is taking code and factoring it into new, simpler parts) it reads much better: To get a food, we have an array of foods and we pick one at random.

Keep this kind of stuff in mind while you work, and as you learn C++ you can make better code. Anytime you repeat a task that isn't trivial, make it a function. Suddenly that task is trivial, because you don't care about how the function works (that's in the function), just what the function does (that's the function name).

Comment: Many reasons for a downvote here - principally magic numbers. But I'll let you off this time.

Comment: @Neil: Fair enough. :) How's this? :P

Answer (score 2):

Look here:

```
int d = rand() % (8 - 1 + 1) + 1;
```

This will return a number between 1 and 8 *inclusive*. What you need is this:

```
int d = rand() % 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going outside the bounds of the array. The array object begins at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have

```
int d = rand() % (8 - 1 + 1) + 1;
```

Why not just use

```
int d = rand() % 8;
```

Comment: because im a noob and dont fully understand rand lol thanks. can you better explain rand to me please?

Comment: @TimothyTech, for some reason Stackoverflow didn't tell me about this comment until it was way too late, sorry. `rand` returns a random number between 0 and some larger number specified as RAND_MAX. Since it starts at zero, taking the mod will also give a result that starts at zero, which is what you want for indexing into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think modern c++ compilers will still let you use an old C trick for static arrays:

```
string CreateFood()
{
     char* nameArray = {"spagetti", "ChickenSoup", "Menudo"};
     // note the trick to get the compiler to count the array elements for you:
     int d = rand() % (sizeof(nameArray) / sizeof(nameArray[0]));   
     return std::string( nameArray[d] );
}
```